# Where is the code block habdling the creation of Delivery document from sales order in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

[image]

I can't seem to find the code responsible for the creation of a delivery document when confirm button is clicked in a sales order, I want to make some changes to the data that is being passed from the sales order to the delivery document upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

You may turn on debug mode and then hover on confirm button, you should see the name of button (ex: action_confirm...) this is the name of the function to be called when we click on the button. After getting the name of the function, you can go to the sale module and search for the name.